# Why doesn't this .htaccess file redirect properly?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, rewritecond

I have a web application with multiple pages.  The .htaccess file redirects everything after the domain-name.com/ to my index.php file, which processes the input and renders the appropriate page.

However, I also have some actual directories under domain-name.com/ which need to be excepted from the redirect.  For example, my PHPMyAdmin directory (/pma).

Everything was working fine until I added the line to redirect reports/[name] to the index page also.  Now, my /pma doesn't go to the PMA directory and instead goes to my app's index.php.

If I use /pma/index.php, it works, but it doesn't make sense why /pma would stop working with that one new rewrite rule.

Commenting out the RewriteRule for reports causes everything to work again.

I can't figure out why.  Thanks for any help!

.htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect http to https (http://htaccesscheatsheet.com/#force-https)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}


# Ignore the following directories (don't remap to page engine)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(pma*|css)

#Redirect all /reports/[report name] requests to index.php?page=reports/[report name]
RewriteRule ^reports/([a-z0-9\-_]+)\/{0,1}$ index.php?page=reports/$1   [NC,QSA,L]

#Redirect all /[pagename] requests to index.php?page=[pagename]&[querystring]
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)\/{0,1}$ index.php?page=$1   [NC,QSA,L]


# Return .json files with the correct mime type (needed to support manifest.json)
AddType application/json .json
```

Comment: `/pma/index.php` would "work" because it doesn't match the `RewriteRule` _pattern_. You don't need to escape slashes in the mod_rewrite regex (but you've not escaped them all). `\/{0,1}` is the same as `/?`.

Answer (score 3):

`RewriteCond` only [applies](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) to the next `RewriteRule`. You now have two rules, each of which need the exception.

So just repeat that `RewriteCond` line like this:

```
#Redirect all /[pagename] requests (with exceptions) to index.php?page=[pagename]&[querystring]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^\/(pma*|css)
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\-_]+)\/{0,1}$ index.php?page=$1   [NC,QSA,L]
```

An alternative way to do it, if you like PCRE regular expressions is something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(?!pma|css)([a-z0-9\-_]+)\/{0,1}$ index.php?page=$1   [NC,QSA,L]
```

However, that's a bit obscure.  If you're going to have several rules with exceptions, then I'd accept David's solution is easier to read.

Comment: `!^\/(pma*|css)` - that asterisk looks erroneous (but harmless as it happens).

Answer (score 3):

Exceptions like this are easier to apply as final rules that don't do any rewriting. Replace your `RewriteCond` line with:

```
RewriteRule ^pma/ - [L]
RewriteRule ^css/ - [L]
```